# Creating multiple family trees in C

Tags: c, data-structures

I have text file structure like this:

```
NAME son
MOTHER mother
FATHER father

NAME father
MOTHER grandmother 

NAME otherson
FATHER otherfather
MOTHER other mother
```

As output I should get something like this:

Task is to print family tree. Separate different families. Person description always starts with NAME. Program should be written in C . Output can be printed in console or either in new text file.

I tried to write program which takes input from file and create node for each person, also mother and father. Put all nodes in array, and now thinking what should I do next.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 63

typedef struct node
{
    char* name;
    struct node *mom; //left
    struct node *dad; //right
} t_node;

t_node* createNode(char* name) {
    t_node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(t_node));
    if (newNode == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    newNode->name = strdup(name); // Allocate memory for the name and copy it
    newNode->mom = NULL;
    newNode->dad = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

void freeMemory(t_node* nodeArray[], int numNodes){
    for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
        free(nodeArray[i]->name);
        free(nodeArray[i]);
    }
}

void printNodes(t_node* nodeArray[], int numNodes){
    printf("Nodes created:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", nodeArray[i]->name);
    }
}

int main() {
    FILE *fin;
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    char* name;

    fin = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if(fin == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening input file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    t_node* nodeArray[10000]; // Array to store pointers to created nodes
    int numNodes = 0;

    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fin) != NULL) {
        if (strstr(line, "VARDS")) {
            name = strstr(line, "NAME") + 6;
            name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0; // Remove newline character

            // Create a node for the person
            t_node* person = createNode(name);
            nodeArray[numNodes++] = person;
        } else if (strstr(line, "FATHER")) {
            char* father = strstr(line, "TEVS") + 5;
            father[strcspn(father, "\n")] = 0;
        
            // Create a node for the father if not already created
            int found = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
                if (strcmp(nodeArray[i]->name, father) == 0) {
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                t_node* fatherNode = createNode(father);
                nodeArray[numNodes++] = fatherNode;
            }
        } else if (strstr(line, "MOTHER")) {
            char* mother = strstr(line, "MATE") + 5;
            mother[strcspn(mother, "\n")] = 0;

            // Create a node for the mother if not already created
            int found = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
                if (strcmp(nodeArray[i]->name, mother) == 0) {
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                t_node* motherNode = createNode(mother);
                nodeArray[numNodes++] = motherNode;
            }
        }
        //one iteration through 1 person with mother and father
    }

    fclose(fin);

   printNodes(nodeArray, numNodes);
   freeMemory(nodeArray, numNodes);

    return 0;
}
```

I need help with making relations between nodes. Can't figure out how to do this.
Also somehow need to prevent cycling(A is B father, B is father to A), don't take incorrect input, for example, if person has 2 mothers.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to create is a data structure in which each node has two predecessors (two parents). Also, a node has a list (or an array) of children.
Build up a structure and the "add" function keeping that in mind.

For instance, you could define a structure like:

```
typedef struct node
{
    char* name;
    struct node *mom;
    struct node *dad;
    struct node **children; //Array of children
 } t_node;
```

In this way, when you add a new node, you can attach it to their children or parents, and, at the same time, you could think about printing the entire tree by "levels".

Is it clear?

Comment: If we will print tree by levels(generations) how to ensure that we can print multiple trees(different families) not only just generations in one tree?

Comment: Oh yeah, in this case you have to keep a list of ancestors (the root of every tree) and go through them. This is, in fact, a forest.